# Conditional default route in Angular.js

Tags: routes, angularjs

How to make Angular.js to go to /route1 by default if the $rootScope.isAdmin==true, but if isAdmin is false or does not exist - go to /route2 ?

isAdmin is set in a login controller:

```
.controller(
  'LoginController',
['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', 'authService',
  ($scope, $rootScope, $http, authService) ->
    $scope.submit = ->
      try
        $http.post("/users/sign_in",
          user:
            email: @username
            password: @password
            remember_me: if @remember_me then 1 else 0
        ).success (response) ->
          $rootScope.isAdmin = response[0].is_admin
          authService.loginConfirmed()
      catch ex
        alert ex
])
```

Comment: Are you looking for something more than $location.path(put_appropriate_route_here)? Or is that sufficient?

Comment: Here is the similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657711/redirect-index-page-if-user-is-logged-in-angularjs/14658126#14658126

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541695/redirecting-to-a-certain-route-based-on-condition Try this.